# python sqlite3 unrecognized token

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to do some simple operations in sqlite with python. I have the test database created and have created a table but when I try to insert my data into it I get an 'unrecognized token' error.

> c.execute("create table node(changeset int, uid int, timestamp text, lon real, visible int, version int, user text, lat real, id int)")

Creates the table. but when I try to insert the first line of data:

> c.execute("insert into node values(8581395,451048,2011-0629T14:14:14Z,-87.6939548,true,5,bbmiller,41.9729565,261114299)")

I get the error:

OperationalError: unrecognized token: "29T14"

What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
c.execute("insert into node values(8581395,451048,2011-0629T14:14:14Z,-87.6939548,true,5,bbmiller,41.9729565,261114299)")
```

should be

```
c.execute("insert into node values(8581395, 451048, '2011-0629T14:14:14Z', -87.6939548, 1, 5, 'bbmiller', 41.9729565, 261114299)")
```

Notice two relevant changes:

1. I've changed all the text fields to be nested into quote marks
2. True becomes an Integer as SQLite do not store booleans as an specific type.

From https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html:

> SQLite does not have a separate Boolean storage class. Instead,
>   Boolean values are stored as integers 0 (false) and 1 (true).

Thus the boolean values comming from python must be translated into 0
or 1.